# Don't remove tags that are only used once in the last 6 months

Tags: feature-request, tags

One issue with tagging on Web Applications is the tag removal script which automatically deletes tags that have only been used once in the past six months.

This tag removal script has led to [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions about low-use services such as [goodfilms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goodfilms), [openraid](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openraid), [microsoft-answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-answers), and [koding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koding). Other sites like [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/181240) have voted to have tag auto-deletion disabled in the past and it hasn't caused any issues.

**Can we disable auto-deletion of single use tags on Web Applications?**

Comment: What was the argument on Arqade to turn off the one-use tag removal? What is the argument to turn off it here? Just because it was done there and "it hasn't caused any issues"? How do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

On [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com) they are using tags in a way that I think that doesn't apply to Web Applications.  I'm not sure about the arguments on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com). According to Jeff Attwood's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/289691) to [Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48417/289691) the point of the automatic single-use tag removal is to remove tags added by accident and this was set because occurs frequently. I think that this happens on Web Applications, so it's could be that turning off the automatique one-use tag removal could cause more harm that benefits.

I think that having six months time window to do something to "save" a tag is enough. If we want to prevent that a tag be removed at this we have two options:

1. Post a second question
2. Add a tag wiki

Regad

---

These tags reapered but still have only one question and haven't a tag wiki

- [goodfilms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goodfilms)
- [microsoft-answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-answers)
- [koding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koding)

This tag has't a question

- [openraid](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openraid)

At this time, we only had five questions with [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

- [How do I set the list icon?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107633/88163)

  As the question mentioned "Microsoft's advertising" I added [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) to it.
- [Filling up the Roster on OpenRaid](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66968/88163)
- [Use Computer Modern font on Draft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43745/88163)
- [How to download all di.fm & sky.fm playlists at once?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21798/88163)
- [See the actual queries and actions Acunetix is testing with](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13047/88163)